# Android. Many screens/layouts to make in application. Which is the most optimized?

Tags: android, layout

I have to make a lot of different screens (fragments). One layouts is in anothers, like tabs. Sometimes tabs have another tabs. I'm looking for the best way to optimize it.
Now I'm using frame and linear containers, changing content by `FragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(null, null).commit()`, but it seams to use a lot of RAM. Maybe `ViewPager`?

Answer (score 2):

Be sure that you are not holding references to old Fragments in some singleton, or some other object. Memory leaks are always first suspects whan to much memory is being used.
Use [leakcanary](https://github.com/square/leakcanary) library to check that. It's easiest way.